# Time complexity for python list comparing

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

I was wondering what the time complexity of this algorithm should be. As it is written in python, the step, if (l1 == l2): is of time O(n) and it stops the program immediately. So, taking the outer loop into account, what might the time complexity be?

Assume:
l1 and l2 have same length, n
there must be at least an element that is not the same between l1 and l2

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if (l1[i] != l2[i]):
        l2[i] = l1[i]
        if (l1 == l2):
           return True
        else:
           return False
```

My initial idea is that, given that there must be one element that is not same in l1 and l2, in the worst case, if that element is the last element, then, we iterate l1 completely, and at the last element, we change that element for l2 and when we do so, l1 becomes equal to l2.
So, iterating l1 takes O(n) time and then comparing l1==l2 takes n time. But the thing is, this l1==l2 is only running one time in the whole algorithm. So, is the time complexity O(2n)?

Comment: O(2n) is the same as O(n). And yes, the worst case time complexity is O(n). If there's exactly one element different, the runtime is Theta(n).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `n` is the length of the input lists `l1` and `l2`:

1- The `for` loop iterates over the length of the input lists, which is `len(l1)`, therefore, this loop has a time complexity of `O(n)`.

2- Inside the loop, the condition `l1[i] != l2[i]` is checked. This operation has a constant time complexity of `O(1)` as it compares two elements.

3- If the condition is true, `l2[i]` is updated and checks if `l1` is equal to `l2` using the condition `l1 == l2`. This comparison has a time complexity of `O(n)` because it needs to compare each element of the lists.

4- If the condition `l1 == l2` is true, the function immediately returns `True`, which stops the program. This return statement has a constant time complexity of `O(1)`.

5- If the condition `l1 == l2` is false, the function immediately returns `False`, which stops the program. This return statement also has a constant time complexity of `O(1)`.

So, the overall time complexity of the algorithm is `O(n)`. The worst-case scenario occurs when the first non-matching element in the lists is at the end, causing the loop to iterate through all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

@HosseinTaghizad already gave you wonderful explanation. I just wanted to add is,
yes T.C. is indeed `O(n) + O(n) = O(2n)`

But the thing is, we don't usually consider these constant values. Because as the complexity of the input increases, let say we are dealing with a input size of 10^10, Constant term becomes insignificant . That's why we usually ignore those. Thus `O(k * n)` will always be `O(n)` where k is a constant term